# Generic Iqueryable filter

Tags: .net, generics, filter

I'm trying to refactor current filtering solution.
I have 3 classes:

```
class A : C { }
class B : C { }
class C { }
```

and there is a method that accepts generic parameter:

```
private static IQueryable<T> ApplyFilter<T>(IQueryable query, Filter filter)
{
    IQueryable<C> qq = query.Cast<C>();
    if(q == null)
        throw new Exception("can not cast");
    // applying filter
    return (IQueryable<T>) q; 
}
```

The last line (return) throws an exception: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[C]' to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[A]'."

Does anyone know how to fix it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using `IQueryable<T> qq = Query.Cast<T>();` instead of hard-coding to `C` ? note: while an `IQueryable<A>` can be assigned to `IQueryable<C>` (via variance), it is *not* true that an `IQueryable<C>` can be assigned to an `IQueryable<A>` (unless the underlying type genuinely is one)

Comment: I didn't tried casting it to T,since it is already T type. "IQueryable<C> can be assigned to an IQueryable<A>", is any other way to do that filter wihtout using this casting? I read about Expression, it might help, but it takes more time to implement.

Comment: in the question, it is not "of type T"; it is the non-generic API. It isn't really very clear what you are doing here. Do you have an example of the caller?

Comment: it is called from this method:

`private static IQueryable<T> ProcessA<T>(IQueryable<A> query,....)
{
    query = ApplyFilter(query, filter.SubFilter);
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work by adding an interface D. The final solution looks like:

```
private static IQueryable<T> ApplyFilter<T>(IQueryable query, Filter filter)
    where T: class, DInterface
{
    // can access C class props
    return query; 
}
```